# Story about parallel dimension travelling with an artificial intelligence

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

I am trying to find a book I read recently (in the past year) about the main character being hired by an AI to take its robot along with him and travel the parallel dimensions to find the limit of the travel (or something along these lines). I also remember the story had something about the traveller not being able to carry more then a certain amount of material with them. In the story there is a massive social impact of the parallel travelling too cause some people could not travel and had to be left behind.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it the Accidental Time Machine by Joe Haldeman? This story contains many similarities to your post. Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Accidental_Time_Machine

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175842/co-authored-novel-involving-joshua-and-sallys-travels-into-the-past (which is newer but has an answer confirmed by OP)

Answer (score 12):

If it is fairly recent it may be Pratchett and Baxter's [*The Long Earth*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Earth). A good yarn, though the ending was not wholly satisfying to my mind.

The limit of quantity you could move came from having to *pick up* bodily whatever you wanted to bring. The AI got around it by making the airship *his body*.

The AI claimed to be a reincarnated Tibetan motorcycle repairman. The protagonist is one of a small class of humans who can shift (or "step") naturally; others have to use a simple, handmade (or at least hand-finished) electric device (most often powered by a potato). Mostly people also experience a period of profound nausea after stepping though the natural steppers seem to be immune.

The sequel *The Long War* is in the bookstores now, and apparently a third volume is planned (to be called *The Long Childhood* according to wikipedia).