# Co-authored novel, involving Joshua and Sally's travels into the past

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

There was a book by two authors in which characters are able to travel into the past. The main character was named Joshua and had a friend called Sally. The authors are most probably British as I had read the book in British Council Library. In the book, people time travel by holding a small device.

Comment: We're going to know a few more details, things like when you read it, or when it may have been published. We're also going to need a lot more details than them being able to travel by holding a device as that's a common trope. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help you add in some more details.

Comment: Knowing the character's names is an enormous help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [The Long Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Earth) by Terry Pratchett and Stephen Baxter.

The device you're referring to is a 'stepper'.

> **Joshua Valienté:** an orphan, born on another world when his mother stepped during childbirth. A natural stepper.
>
> **Sally Linsay:** daughter of the inventor of the "Stepper" box, a device that allows the majority of humans to step between parallel universes. A natural stepper and later romantic interest to Joshua Valienté.

For the record, there's no time-travel in this book, only dimensional travel.

Comment: Thank you. That is the book I am looking for. Ah! Right, dimensional travel. But they are able to travel where Joshua encounters very old animals. Isn't that time travel?

Comment: @ShantanuHebbar - It's parallel worlds, not time travel. Occasionally they travel to a world where the dinosaurs didn't die out, but it's still always the same year